# memorizing the value with using useMemo with useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a `useSelector` that returns some value. I'd like to remember some mapped value derived from it:

```js
const value = useSelector(...);
const mapped = useMemo(() => value.map(...), [?]); // value?
```

What should I pass into array of dependencies? I'm asking because `useSelector` returns new ref for each render.

Maybe there is something more suitable than `useMemo`?

Comment: useSelector is a function hook. try to wrap the ```useSelector``` with a ```useCallback``` and see what's happen. This is just my untried opinion, not a fact or answer.

Comment: If your computation in `value.map(...)` only depends on `value`, you should simply specify `useMemo(() => value.map(...), [value])`

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi, one hook cannot be inside other

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi React hooks can only be called from React function components and custom React hooks. You can't call `useSelector` in the callback function passed to the `useCallback` hook.

Comment: @motto, value is ref, idk why, but each render `useSelector` returns new ref (value doesn't change)

Comment: Perhaps you can share your selector, or a cut-down version of your selector.

Comment: Why would any part of the redux state change ***just*** because *this* component rendered/rerendered? This seems like a code smell. What is this state being selected and what is updating it?

Comment: it looks like the whole state is being updated, and therefore the update in the component is twitching. can it affect?
moreover, the values are the same, the ref changes

Comment: At the risk of scope creep on the question, can you [edit] to include some of the redux code, specifically *at least* the state slice/reducer for the state value you are selecting above. If more of the combined state tree is necessary to see where the issue lies then please include that as well.

Comment: oh, apparently I searched badly because I just had to use the `isEqual` argument of `useSelector`, this may stop the return of new refs.
anyway,

Answer (score 1):

If `value` is the only variable referenced in the `useMemo` callback then `value` is the dependency you would specify.

```js
const value = useSelector(...);
const mapped = useMemo(() => value.map(...), [value]);
```

You could also just compute the `mapped` value via the selector function.

```
const mapped = useSelector(state => {
  const value = state....;
  return value.map(...)
});
```